# How do I align my output when a word is too long?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program where the user enters 5 candidates for an election along with their number of votes. The program's output creates a table where it shows each candidates name, their votes, percentage of votes, and the winner of the election. My code is below and a sample of the output is in a picture that I have uploaded.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

const int numofcandidates = 5;
// declare variables and arrays
string candidateName[numofcandidates] = { "" };
int candidatevotes[numofcandidates];
float totalvotepercentage;

// declare methods
void takeNameandVote();
void printTable();



int main()
{
    takeNameandVote();
    printTable();
}

void takeNameandVote()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numofcandidates; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter last name for candidate " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> candidateName[i];
        cout << "Enter number of votes for this candidate: ";
        cin >> candidatevotes[i];
    }
}

void printTable()
{
    // to set up % of total votes
    int totalvotes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numofcandidates; i++)
    {
        totalvotes += candidatevotes[i];
    }
    cout << "Candidate\tVotes Received\t\t" << '%' << " of Total Votes" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numofcandidates; i++)
    {
        
        cout  << candidateName[i] << '\t' <<  setw(18) << candidatevotes[i] << "\t" << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << setw(16) << (candidatevotes[i] / (double)totalvotes * 100) << endl;

    }
    cout << "Total\t\t" << setw(10) << totalvotes << endl;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all `\t`s and only use [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(18) << candidateName[i] 
          << std::right << std::setw(8) << candidatevotes[i] << ...
```